# BrowserCouch, help with basic example

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'm trying to get a basic example of BrowserCouch working... the one shown here: http://hg.toolness.com/browser-couch/raw-file/blog-post/tutorial.html

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="browser-couch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    BrowserCouch.get('blog-posts',
                 function onRetrieveCb(db) {
                   blogDb = db; /* Save the DB for later. */ 
                 });
</script>
```

I get this error in the Chrome and FF console:

> BrowserCouch is not defined

I've double checked and the browser-couch.js file is correctly src'd.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Does this fiddle work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eRMkh/ Try it with the console open.

Comment: The version of browser-couch.js here gives the error (mentioned above): https://github.com/mikeal/browsercouch/blob/master/browser-couch.js  .... But, the version in your fiddle (and sourced from the BrowserCouch tutorial) does not give the error http://hg.toolness.com/browser-couch/raw-file/blog-post/js/browser-couch.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using code from the [blog post](http://hg.toolness.com/browser-couch/raw-file/blog-post/tutorial.html) but using a newer version of the JavaScript and the newer one has a different API. From the [github page](https://github.com/mikeal/browsercouch):

```
var database = BrowserCouch('foo');
database.onload(function(){
    database.get('bar', function(d){console.log(d)});
});
```

But the older version wanted what you're doing:

```
BrowserCouch.get('blog-posts',
    function onRetrieveCb(db) {
        blogDb = db; /* Save the DB for later. */ 
    }
);
```

So I think you need to match your API usage to the library version.